# Problems with SJCL "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, sjcl

Using [Sjcl](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) i try to write a little service sending and receiving encrypted data from my javascript application.

Sadly, the [sjcl documentation](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/) is lacking information on how to process their `AES` encrypted data.
Their [encrypt method](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.json.html#.encrypt) returns an object containing serveral attributes of which i can only guess what is what.

```
{"iv":"i0t5BttfXwtY6hxuFSZxJg==",
"v":1,
"iter":1000,
"ks":128,
"ts":64,
"mode":"ccm",
"cipher":"aes",
"salt":"MZ8hpbz+5hU=",
"ct":"n5mR5jwawYwsaUV0xbcYXrcCXPWjR5qMG23qU5Spguz4jpjG5QdFMWSf"}
```

I can identify `iter`, `ks`, `ts`, `mode`, `cipher` and `salt`. My guess is that `ct` is the cipher text, representing the encrypted data. But what is `v` and `iv`?

I tried decrypting my cipher text giving `ct` as a parameter and even tried giving the whole result as a parameter but it always just produces errors:

```
var result = sjcl.json.encrypt(
  'pw123', 
  '{text: "this should be decrypted"}', 
  parameters, 
  rp
);

var originalText = sjcl.json.decrypt(
  'pw123', 
  result.ct,
  parameters,
  rp);

// Results in:
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

How do i decrypt my `ct` using their [decrypt](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.json.html#.decrypt) method?
Anyone any experience with this and can give a brief example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption/decryption works with the default parameters:

```
var result = sjcl.json.encrypt(
  'pw123', 
  '{text: "this should be decrypted"}'
);

var originalText = sjcl.json.decrypt(
  'pw123', 
  result);
```

> But what is `v` and `iv`?

`v` is probably the version information for the ciphertext so that later versions of SJCL can decrypt it. It is simply set to 1 and never used in the [code](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/convenience.js).

The `iv` is the initialization vector that is needed for most block cipher modes such as CCM. For AES it is 16 bytes long or simply the block size.

Comment: my problem was that i didn't see that the result was an already stringified JSON and not an object.
I tried to access ct.
And in the other case i did overwrite a few parameters that where already in the resultset.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem in my Example was that i tried to acces `result.ct` but result is a [`stringified JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) so accessing it's attribute `ct` *obviously* returned `undefined`.

In my other attempt i overwrote parameters by passing `parameters`. Decrypting without passing additional parameters worked - the initial parameters where already given in the `result` stringified JSON.

The updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/e5rqogm3/1/